# vector element not updating

Tags: c++

how come the i.X and i.Y are not being updated in the fb.Entities collection?

am I doing something wrong? I'm learning, Is this the correct way to update values of something in a vector?

```
    for (Entity i : fb.Entities) 
    {
        if (i.Serial == SerialID)
        {
            i.X = (USHORT)((data[5] << 8) + data[6]);
            i.Y = (USHORT)((data[7] << 8) + data[8]);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
for (Entity& i : fb.Entities)
```

to take the actual entity, not a copy.

Answer (score 3):

You need to take *references* to the container elements:

```
for (Entity & i : fb.Entities)  { /* ... */ }
//         ^^^
```

Alternatively:

```
for (auto & i : fb.Entities)
```

(Otherwise, `i` will be a *copy* of the container element, and so any changes to it are lost.)