# The element of vector not updating

Tags: c++, stdvector

```
//simply print each elements in a vector
template<class Iterp>
void print_iter(Iterp begin, Iterp end, std::string delim=", ", std::string ending="\n"){
    int len = (end-begin);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len-1; i++)
    {
        std::cout << (*(begin+i)) << delim;
    }
    if (len>1){
        std::cout << (*(end-1));
    }
    std::cout << ending;
}    

template<class A, class B>
void pr(A first, A end, std::vector<std::vector<B>> &the_result){
    int len = end-first;
    for (size_t a = 0; a < len; a++)
    {
        for (size_t b = 0; b < len; b++)
        {
            for (size_t c = 0; c < len; c++)
            {
                //theres a bunch ways i tried to save these in "the_result" variable, and I ended up with this.
                std::vector<B> result(first, end);
                result.at(a) = (*(first+a));
                result.at(b) = (*(first+b));
                result.at(c) = (*(first+c));
                
                print_iter(result.begin(), result.end());
                //the problem is the "result" variable is not updating using .at() function. So the "result" variable content is still 1, 2, 3.
                

                the_result.push_back(result); //this is not the problem since the "result" variable is still 1, 2, 3

                // std::cout << (*(first+a)) << " " << (*(first+b)) << " " << (*(first+c))
                // But, this one shows it's producing the right permutations.
            }
            
        }
                
    }
    
}
    int main(){
        std::vector<int> test{1, 2, 3}; //tried to create the permutations of this
        int n = 27; //3^3 = 27

        std::vector<std::vector<int>> result(n, std::vector<int>(test.begin(), test.end()));
/*hoping to save all the permutations in "result" variable, each as a vector. ex:
    123
    113
    111
    ...

*/
        pr(test.begin(), test.end(), result);
    }
```

So I tried to create a function to produce permutation with repeated elements and hoping to save each permutation in a 2-dimensional vector.
However, I even cannot update the "result" variable vector using .at() function, pointer element. but when I print it manually, it's showing it's the right answer.

I also explored some other StackOverflow with similar problems, no answer works for me.
[vector element not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004546/vector-element-not-updating)

[Why is my elements in my vector of objects not updating upon calling one of the objects member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657258/why-is-my-elements-in-my-vector-of-objects-not-updating-upon-calling-one-of-the)

[Dereference vector pointer to access element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910712/dereference-vector-pointer-to-access-element)
//tried to use pointer but still doesn't work

Where I made the mistake?

Comment: please include a [mcve]. What you posted is just a template. Its not a function and we don't know how you call the function

Comment: @idclev463035818 oh yeah sorry, i forgot

Comment: You never update `the_result` in the function.

Comment: @TedLyngmo not even the_result variable, the core problem is "result' variable in pr() is not updating

Comment: the code you posted does not produce any output. Are you using a debugger? In that case you need to be specific at what point in the program you observed the values

Comment: @idclev463035818 actually I have another function that simply prints each element in a vector. Please try to lookup the content of "result" variable in pr() function

Comment: You set `result` at its final size, and then `push_back` vectors in it.

Comment: You could use a debugger or just print what you are about to assign, like `std::cout << a << '=' << *(first+a) << ' ' << b << '=' << *(first+b) << ' ' << c << '=' << *(first+c) << '\n';` and it'll become obvious.

Comment: @TedLyngmo notice that I tried to print the "result" content manually using std::cout <<. The output shows the right answer for me.

Comment: @KevinAgusto Notice that you assign the same values already present in the vector after the initialization: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WrM1hb This becomes very clear if you add the debugging line I suggested that you add.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is flawed:

```
   result.at(a) = (*(first+a));
   result.at(b) = (*(first+b));
   result.at(c) = (*(first+c));
```

No matter what are the values of `a`,`b` and `c`, you assign the same numbers to the same elements in each iteraton. They are the same elements you used to initialize `result`.

For `3` elements you rather need something along the line of:

```
   result[1] = (*(first+a));
   result[2] = (*(first+b));
   result[3] = (*(first+c));
```

Comment: unfortunately, std::next_permutation is not producing the repeated symbols (eg: 111, 112, ...). however your example is setting the result with constant values. How can I make it dynamically so it's processing arbitrary lenght of vector?

Comment: @KevinAusto because thats not permutations ;)

Comment: @KevinAgusto sorry I missed that you actually wrote "permutations with repetitions" I'll remove that part

Comment: Yes, thats why i tried to create my own function, but without recursive.

Comment: @KevinAgusto please open a new question for that. The question here was "Why are the vector elements not updated?" and thats what I tried to answer

Comment: However, i still curios why the std::cout in pr() function showing me the correct answer. I just need to save that result to another variable

Comment: @KevinAgusto please don't take it as an offense but I was answering the question before your edit and now I am not really willing to change it. Please make sure you post a [mcve] and include desired and actual output next time

Comment: @KevinAgusto or hope for a better answer, but actually modifying a question to ask for something else is always a little problematic